# Object DOMDocument should be created error

Tags: magento, magento-2.0

I have recently created a new installation of Magento. Unzipped the package and uploaded it with FTP to my website.
After doing the installation wizard, all was installed except for css files etc. I had to run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy for those files.

Now everything works fine, but several menu items on the admin page are not reachable. I receive following error page:

**There has been an error processing your request


Object DOMDocument should be created.


Error log record number: 785367817912**

I have no idea what this error means, when i look at error log record number: 785367817912 i see the following:

> a:4:{i:0;s:37:"Object DOMDocument should be created.";i:1;s:10020:"#0 /home/thomas/domains/thomasvanbeveren.be/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Config/Reader.php(95): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\DomMerger->getDom()
>   #1 /home/thomas/domains/thomasvanbeveren.be/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(261): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\Reader->read()
>   #2 /home/thomas/domains/thomasvanbeveren.be/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(169): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->prepare('adminhtml.cache...')
> ....etc

Can anyone help me with this? Would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try to do a bin/magento...  cache:flush, setup:upgrade and setup:di:compile